# Why does dotnet build on ubuntu output a dll file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04

I have a very simple question. When I use `donet build` on a c# project in ubuntu it outputs a `.dll` file. I was wondering why or how it does that and why does it not output a `.so` file ?

Comment: It will output .dll files, you need to have a dotnet runtime installed on your ubuntu server to run those .dll files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because .NET Core (and .NET as a whole) uses the Portable Executable format even for other platforms, it's still technically a dynamic link library.

The .NET Core run-time loader can read and run it fine.

You can read more here - [.NET assembily file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/file-format)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Lloyd :) Does that mean that if a .dll file is made with `dotnet build` in Windows that it can then be run in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Only with some form of .NET runtime (Core, Mono etc) to load it, it's not a _native_ binary.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core uses it's own file system that has to be ran with a specific command in order to run the application.

> (It) relies on the presence of a shared system-wide version of .NET Core on the target system

To run the application you type in

```
dotnet {FileName}.dll
```

This will start running the application using the .NET Core framework.

> Your app contains only its own code and any third-party dependencies
>   that are outside of the .NET Core libraries. FDDs contain .dll files
>   that can be launched by using the dotnet utility from the command
>   line. For example, dotnet app.dll runs an application named app.

Source: [.NET Core Application Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)